# Cannot run my spring boot app into docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gradle

I use spring boot and gradle.

I have the following message when trying to execute my docker-compose:

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
The message received from the daemon indicates that the daemon has disappeared.
Build request sent: Build{id=febb803a-62f7-4cb8-aee9-32eec7a26b25, currentDir=/app}
Attempting to read last messages from the daemon log...
Daemon pid: 33
  log file: /home/gradle/.gradle/daemon/4.10/daemon-33.out.log
----- Last  20 lines from daemon log file - daemon-33.out.log -----
20:21:56.951 [ERROR] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] Command execution: started DaemonCommandExecution[command = Build{id=febb803a-62f7-4cb8-aee9-32eec7a26b25, currentDir=/app}, connection = DefaultDaemonConnection: socket connection from /127.0.0.1:42597 to /127.0.0.1:33252] after 0.0 minutes of idle
20:21:56.951 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonRegistryUpdater] Marking the daemon as busy, address: [371cc208-366e-411c-bda9-1976aad9f6d3 port:42597, addresses:[/127.0.0.1]]
20:21:56.952 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry] Marking busy by address: [371cc208-366e-411c-bda9-1976aad9f6d3 port:42597, addresses:[/127.0.0.1]]
20:21:56.952 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire exclusive lock on daemon addresses registry.
20:21:56.952 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
20:21:56.961 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
20:21:56.961 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] resetting idle timer
20:21:56.962 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] daemon is running. Sleeping until state changes.
20:21:56.965 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy] Daemon is about to start building Build{id=febb803a-62f7-4cb8-aee9-32eec7a26b25, currentDir=/app}. Dispatching build started information...
20:21:56.966 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.SynchronizedDispatchConnection] thread 15: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.BuildStarted
20:21:56.971 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment] Configuring env variables: {PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin, GRADLE_VERSION=4.2.1, JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk, OLDPWD=/app, XFILESEARCHPATH=/usr/dt/app-defaults/%L/Dt, LANG=C.UTF-8, GRADLE_HOME=/opt/gradle, HOSTNAME=d60c61662320, JAVA_ALPINE_VERSION=8.131.11-r2, LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/../lib/amd64, NLSPATH=/usr/dt/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N.cat, PWD=/app, JAVA_VERSION=8u131, HOME=/home/gradle, SHLVL=2}
20:21:56.977 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.SynchronizedDispatchConnection] thread 13: received class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.CloseInput
20:21:56.977 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultDaemonConnection] thread 13: Received IO message from client: org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.CloseInput@5c4871dc
20:21:56.983 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient] About to start relaying all logs to the client via the connection.
20:21:56.984 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient] The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 33). The daemon log file: /home/gradle/.gradle/daemon/4.10/daemon-33.out.log
20:21:56.987 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth] Starting build in new daemon [memory: 1.0 GB]
20:21:56.988 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput] Closing daemon's stdin at end of input.
20:21:56.988 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput] The daemon will no longer process any standard input.
20:21:56.995 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild] The daemon has started executing the build.
20:21:57.001 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild] Executing build with daemon context: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=c288d465-1d92-4ed2-ab0f-07e079e7cf1c,javaHome=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk,daemonRegistryDir=/home/gradle/.gradle/daemon,pid=33,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
----- End of the daemon log -----


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

my project : https://github.com/schoolhelper/imagestorage

I run docker like this:
`docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml -f docker-compose.yml up --build`